# Tiempo de espera entre dos métodos en Android

Tags: android

Estoy trabajando con animaciones en Android, tengo dos métodos, uno para animar la cabecera y otro para animar el cuerpo para dar un aspecto de ensamble, pero quiero que entre un método y otro haya un retraso de 1 segundo, ya intente pausando el hilo con Thread.sleep(1000) pero lo que hace es que al pulsar el botón para reproducir las dos animaciones el Sleep lo hace al principio de la reproducción no en medio, quisiera saber si hay una forma de hacer lo que busco

Comment: Añade el código de los que has intentado para que podamos ayudarte. Revisa  [ask]

Comment: Como te han comentado pon el código para saber qué has probado... igualmente has probado a poner el sleep thread usando el onAnimationEnd del setAnimationListener ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para que el tiempo de espera se cuente luego de finalizada la primer animación, debes agregar un `AnimationListener` a esa primer animación (con [setAnimationListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation#setAnimationListener(android.view.animation.Animation.AnimationListener))). Dentro de ese listener hay un método llamado [onAnimationEnd](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener#onAnimationEnd(android.view.animation.Animation)) desde donde podés iniciar la segunda animación.

Para el tiempo de espera te recomendaría que utilices el [startOffset](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation#setStartOffset(long)) de la clase `Animation` en lugar del `Thread.sleep`. Este offset indica justamente cuánto tiempo esperar antes de iniciarla.